# Nuxt.js Full Static - Where to store app configuration file

Tags: nginx, webpack, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js for my web applications but never used the full static generator until now. My CI/CD pipeline builds and deploys a docker image containing of an nginx image with the static generated Nuxt.js app. My problem now is that I can not figure out how to use and load an app configuration file. Of course I could define all environment variables (like `API_URL`) during the build process but then i would have to separate images for each environment which would be unfortune.

My approach that I have in mind would be creating a `config.json` file and maybe having nginx deal with that but how can I tell my web application where he should look for the settings file?

My guess is that maybe people using webpack have come around this problem and know how to deal with it.

Comment: Why not use `.env` file?

Comment: @kissu since the generated app is full static, meaning it consists only of js, css and html and is considered only clientsided

Comment: Not sure about what you meant. An `.env` file can totally inject the variables during the project generation (`yarn generate`). It will still be a universal app (or at least SPA only) even if it's static and hosted on a CDN.

Comment: Maybe I did not describe my problem as clear. After project generation `yarn generate` I have bundled files which will be uploaded to a nginx server under `/var/www/html`. The web app will be available now under `example.com/webapp` and has to access the api `example.com/api`. Now without knowing under which path the web app is served (now `/webapp`, maybe on another instance `/webapp2`), how should the web app try and access a configuration file `settings.json` (Where the api url is stored for example) without knowing its path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to look into this before.
The TLDR is that you cannot have on-runtime variables for the `target: static` build, especially with the way how some modules are made.

More info on this Github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/5100
So yeah, it comes down to have some dynamic webpack configs via your CI/CD, this is how my team handles it at least.

Comment: I see. Related to your github issue, I found an open one: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9170

I guess it comes to this, where I replace the URL to the CDN or configuration file via a bash script before running the containerized application (for now).

Comment: @Sylnois also, Nuxtnation may maybe have some great news announced that could bypass this kind of issue. Feel free to join on 15/16th: https://nuxtnation.com/

Comment: I attended the conference, they even picked my question. The answer was unfortunately "Not possible".